# Different databases with the same models on Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following issue:

I need a different database with the same models for each user (or set of users). I have a way of finding out to which database the user is related. The issue is I always have to use the `using` method on every query I make.

For example:

```
Thing.objects.using('appropriate_database').all()
```

Is there a way to avoid the use of `using` and making the user/database relationship implicit somehow?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to connect to different databases without having to say explicitly to which I want to connect, deducing the correct database from the current logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did it! Let me explain how.

We wrote a custom middleware and registered it as an middleware class inside our settings.py file.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'our.custom.middleware.Class',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

This middleware has a [process_request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/middleware/#process_request) method that creates a thread variable (`from threading import local`) to store the appropriate database name for the current user. Since every request is handled by a different thread, we know that our variable's value won't be accidently changed by another thread.

The next step was creating a [Database Router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) and registering it as such.

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ('our.custom.database.Router',)
```

Attention: The default `settings.py` doesn't have a `DATABASE_ROUTERS` variable. You'll have to create it.

Our custom `Router` has the same implementations for `db_for_read` and `db_for_write`. The only thing these methods do is return the database name stored on our thread variable.

That's it. Now we don't have to call `using` every time we need to recover or save model objects.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad design that can't scale to me.  You have to duplicate the schema every time you add a user.

A better design would have a table USER with one-to-many and many-to-many relations with entities required by each user.

Comment: Hello, @duffymo. I appreciate your thoughts on design. Maybe you are right when you say that the design does not scale. But not every user creates a new database, since it can be linked to an existing one. I do not think I have got what you mean. Do you mean I should have an User object that has a relationship to EVERY table on the database? I do not see how this can be an improvement. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Not every table, just the ones that contain user-specific data.  And it's an improvement because you can add new users simply by INSERTing new data, not modifying the schema.  You shield the consuming application from schema changes.  This is what relational databases are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2nd manager on your models:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_query_set().using('appropriate_database')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # "objects" is the default manager
    objects_db2 = MyModelManager()

    field1 = models.CharField(...)

class MyModel2(models.Model):
    objects_db2 = MyModelManager()
    ...
```

Then use queries `MyModel.objects_db2.filter(...).order_by(...)...`

Comment: Hello, @Ricola3D. Thanks for your answer. I think that with the solution you provided I will just switch problems. Since I won't have to specify the database but I'll have specify the model manager.