# One django Instance with different databases per model

Tags: python, django, django-database

Can I have a Django Instance of a project(one setting file) but different database per model or model instance? What do I mean.

Suppose we have a model Business

```
class Business(models.Model):
    #buisness specific fields
```

A model Employer

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    #other fields
```

Then I create 3 businesses

```
business1 = Business.create(#fields kwords heare)
business2 = Business.create(#etc)
business3 = Business.create(#etc)
```

I want each business to be stored to a different database but on the same server say business1, business2 and business3 respectively.

I also want to have employers but each employer object to be stored to the same data base of its foreign key, so

```
employer1 = Employer.create(business=business1, #...etc) #store it on table on business1 db
employer2 = Employer.create(business=business2, #....etc) #store it on table on business2 db
employer3 = Employer.create(business=business3, #....etc) #store it on table on business3 db.
```

Is this possible with Django?

Comment: How would Django know which db to use when retrieving an object (or even worse - a list of objects)?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought after I posted the question. I read this (http://goo.gl/slJrtK) but that only counts for when db's are pre-defined in settings file. So I guess it probably isn't possible

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? What is your real problem ?

Comment: I wanted each buisness to have each own database. Because this project will hold sensitive data I was wondering if it is more secure to have each buinsess on a database on its own but running one instance of django. I am little concerend of security issues, since its my first big project

Comment: You can find information about having multi database in [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations)

Comment: Yes I allready comented on that, multiple databases in django need to be pre-defined, and then routed, but predefined, I was talking to creating a database at model creation. But I guess it's not possible.

Comment: You can have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18016960), it can be helpful!